# Is a custom partitioner needed for my use case?

Tags: cassandra

I have the following table representing transactions of (fungible) assets between an origin and a destination node:

- Origin (Node). A value between 1 and 1000.
- Id
- Destination (Node). A value between 1 and 1000.
- Qty

Its primary key is (Origin, Id).

I would like the partitions to be available on the following nodes only:

- Origin Node
- Destination Node
- A well-known / pre-determined "Master" Node, which keeps track of all data

Is this possible? Do I need to design this table differently?
Or write a custom partitioner maybe?

Maybe the table can be re-ordered like this:

- Origin (Node)
- Destination (Node)
- Id
- Qty

With primary key (Origin, Destination, Id) and partition key on (Origin, Destination)

So a custom partitioner inheriting from MurmurhashPartitioner and redefining the hash function as "origin*origin + destination" should probably work.

Then, for each node and the "Master" node, assign its custom range.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can implement your own custom partitioner. Cassandra is a fully open-source software after all.

But the fact that you need to ask indicates to me that you most likely don't have the necessary expertise and so it would be a bad idea to do so.

Implementing your own custom classes for the extensible parts of Cassandra is not a bad thing. There are organisations who have done this successfully. But when you do write your own implementation, you have to be prepared for the fact that when you run into issues, you are on your own and won't be able to get support for it.

For me personally, it doesn't make sense to go your own way unless you have a team of Cassandra experts working in your organisation. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.  I am currently reviewing several potential solutions, including Hyperledger for example, with a view to achieving what I have outlined above. So of course we don't have the expertise to operate on Cassandra, or any other distributed solution for that matter.  That being said, writing and testing our own Cassanda partioner, the way I outlined it would take a couple of days.  I would, of course, much prefer to use Cassandra out of the box, but I don't see a way to make it work with the model I outlined.